# How to use jQuery in VUE

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm trying to recreate this sticky column html table https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/gWoVzN

I've run `npm install --save jquery`. I've used it on mounted. But it seems to not work.

 Any idea how to implement jquery inside vue js?

Answer (score 3):

Import jquery in your vue component:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

Comment: I have a table that shows only after a set of inputs are clicked. In my case, I inserted the jQuery code after all the actions are executed. But nothing happens.

Comment: Can you share your code? to see where is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Run the command to install jQuery

```
npm install --save
```

Now you can use it in your component by importing it

```
import $ from "jquery";
```